# split list of tuples into a list of strings in python/django

Tags: python

My original list of tuples was `list1` and I wanted to split the tuple into a list of strings:

```
 list = [Apple, Orange, Grapes]
 list1= [(u"[u'Apple', u'Orange', u'Grapes']",)]
```

I converted it into `list2`

```
list2 = ("[u'Apple', u'Orange', u'Grapes']",)
```

using

```
string_tuple_list = [tuple(map(str, eachTuple)) for eachTuple in list1]
```

but I want to convert this into a list like this:

```
list = [Apple, Orange, Grapes]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What does this have to do with django?

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off looking into why you get a list of a one-tuple of a string representation of a list of strings in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The innermost list is represented as a string and is accessible with `list1[0][0]`. You can then use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert that string into a Python list:

```
from ast import literal_eval
list1 = [(u"[u'Apple', u'Orange', u'Grapes']",)]
fruits = literal_eval(list1[0][0])
print(fruits)
```

Output:

```
[u'Apple', u'Orange', u'Grapes']
```